# How to install Pynma & Twython twitter.updateStatusWithMedia UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, api, push-notification, raspberry-pi, twython

1st Q is how do i install pynma modules?,where should i put the modules? Im new in Python because usually there is setup.py, but pynma do not have setup.py :( im trying to implement notify my android in raspberry pi and im lost .. https://github.com/uskr/pynma

2nd Q is im having problem with Twython updateStatusWithMedia, but with updateStatus it just fine, i can tweet normal message.

here is my code

```
from twython import Twython

twitter = Twython(
                    twitter_token = '52IKIxxxx',
                    twitter_secret = 'SvwK4xmxxxx',
                    oauth_token = '5164xxxxxxx',
                    oauth_token_secret = 'kVkrHxxxxxx'
                   )

twitter.updateStatus(status='hello tweet from raspberry pi 1.47am')
twitter.updateStatusWithMedia("/home/pi/teddy.jpg", status='hello!')
```

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 247: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 247: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 247: ordinal not in range(128)

here is the image of the error

[image]

forgive my english :(

Answer (score 0):

Twython (as of 2.9.0) has the `updateStatusWithMedia` bug fixed. It was an issue with a library upstream that we depend on, but things should be good now. Hope it works out for you, sorry about the delay!